# How to count your user userID to count/select a row in a table?

Tags: php

I'm making a function that i have to check if a userid is in this table already: if not he has to get into another page yet. But for some reason I get "NULL" back instead of the number of the userID.

my class:

```
public function countHobbies($userID){
        try{
            $conn = Db::getConnection();
            $statement = $conn->prepare("select * from hobby where userID = '".$userID."'");
            $userID = $this->getUserID();
            $statement->execute();
            $aantal = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //
            $aantal->execute();
}
        catch(throwable $e){
           $error = "Something went wrong";
       }
    }
```

and this is on my html page:

```
$userArray = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$userID = implode(" ", $userArray);

$hobby = new Hobby();
$count = $hobby->countHobbies($userID);
if($count == false){
    echo "no";
    //header('Location: hobby.php');
}
else{
    echo "yes";
}
```

Comment: that's quite normal, you define `$userID` AFTER your SQL statement...

Comment: also, you should use prepared statements, with userid as a parameter, to be safe against sql injection (if user id comes from browser GET or POST)

Comment: @Pierre also in this case? Cause i use prepared statements if i put something into our databank. Didn't know that i needed that if i just wanted to read something out the databank, even with a variable of the userID. Because I want to use the userID that is used for the session and so the person who is logged

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two things you need to fix:

1. Always use parameter binding on the SQL statement. It may not be a security problem in this particular instance, but do get into the habit of using prepared statements. Because otherwise you'll find yourself in situations where you should've but didn't. https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php
2. The `$userID` variable must be assigned before it is used.

In the end, it could look like this:

```
$userID = $this->getUserID();
$statement = $conn->prepare("select * from hobby where userID = ?");
$statement->bind_param("s", $userID);
```